# Trying to query custom metadata type

Tags: soql

Really short question as I am new to salesforce. I got some queries for objects running but I now need to query for records of a specific custom metadata type. I tried it just like I got objects:

```
.../services/data/v51.0/query?q=Select FIELDS(ALL)+From+SomeObject
```

which works but

```
.../services/data/v51.0/query?q=Select+FIELDS(ALL)+From+MyCustomMetaDataType__mdt
```

doesn't.

ERROR:

> [
> {
> "message": "\nSelect FIELDS(ALL) From MyCustomMetaDataType__mdt\n                        ^\nERROR at Row:1:Column:25\nsObject type 'MyCustomMetaDataType__mdt' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.",
> "errorCode": "INVALID_TYPE"
> }
> ]

Visiblity is set to public and I got the name from "API Name" as stated in Custom Code/Custom Metadata Types.

Also is there a way to view the whole database? Something like a SOQL Explorer?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? A more standard SF approach is to write a custom Apex REST service that performs these operations on-platform.  [Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php) is one tool that shows the "database", there are others if you do a search.

Comment: based on some quick testing, only FIELDS(STANDARD) is supported for custom metadata types